# EditorFor getting data-val-required and other unobtrusive attributes when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation, mvc-editor-templates, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a pretty simple EditorTemplate for currency fields that looks like this:

```
@model Decimal?

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon fa fa-usd"></span>
    @Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("N2"), new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"class", "form-control"},
        {"data-type", "Currency"}
    })
</div>
```

Somehow, when calling this template using EditorFor, it is getting unobtrusive attributes for required and number type without me actually specifying that it is required in the model anywhere:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Amount Raised")]
    public decimal AmountRaised { get; set; }
}
```

**.cshtml**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountRaised)
```

**HTML Result:**

```
<input class="form-control
    data-type="Currency"
    data-val="true"
    data-val-number="The field Amount Raised must be a number."
    data-val-required="The Amount Raised field is required."
    id="AmountRaised"
    name="AmountRaised"
    type="text"
    value=""
    aria-required="true"
    aria-describedby="AmountRaised-error">
```

Obviously marking fields as required that aren't supposed to be is keeping form submits from happening when they should be valid forms.

Is there something I am missing about EditorTemplates that I need to set or change to make sure this doesn't happen without me asking it to?

Answer (score 0):

Types like `decimal` are required by default since they're non-nullable. If you truly want it to be optional you need to make the property a nullable decimal (`decimal?`).